# Stuck with Cisco DHCP pool issue

Tags: cisco, dhcp, pool

Yes, I have searched, googled, sworn, googled more but have not quite found the answer I need, .. I have also posted this on a Cisco forum but, as I discovered at stackoverflow, the Stack* forums generally tend to give clear , easy to understand answers, ... so hi,. and here goes:

I know some cisco basics but it seems my knowledge of the Cisco DHCP pools is less than what I thought.  Our company has several 3825 (1gb mem) routers which we deploy from time to time for small temporary networks when these are required by our customers Now I have to use one of these routers for a group of 500-600 people on WiFi for a two day event.  I took one of my old configs and changed the DHCP pool from 10.10.0.1/24 to 10.10.0.1/22. A assumed that it would just be a matter of changing the pool size and the inverse mask to match.   All seemed to work well until the second range  (ie: 10.10.1.x or 2.x) was given out.  Clients get an IP address but there is no traffic possible to the outside world. I have no idea why. I have posted my config in it's full   with just the passwords removed, there are no public IP's in it so no prob there.

Some extra info: 
My connection is a router provided by the venue, giving me a 192.168.1.1 address on my 0/0 interface.

Although absent in the below config I have tried:

```
    ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1
    ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet0/0
```

Neither of these seem to make any difference,... does anyone have an idea whet I am missing or doing wrong?

Thanks for your time!

```
    version 12.4
    service timestamps debug datetime msec
    service timestamps log datetime msec
    no service password-encryption
    !
    hostname router1
    !
    boot-start-marker
    boot-end-marker
    !
    enable secret PASSWORD

    no aaa new-model
    !
    resource policy
    !
    ip cef
    !
    !
    no ip dhcp use vrf connected
    ip dhcp excluded-address 10.10.0.1 10.10.0.20
    !
    !
    ip dhcp pool pool1
       import all
       network 10.10.0.0 255.255.252.0
       dns-server 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 4.4.2.1 
       default-router 10.10.0.1 
       lease 0 0 10
    !
    !
    !
    voice-card 0
     no dspfarm
    !
    !
    archive
     log config
      hidekeys
    !
    !
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet0/0
     ip address dhcp
     ip nat outside
     ip virtual-reassembly
     duplex auto
     speed auto
     media-type rj45
     negotiation auto
     no keepalive
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet0/1
     ip address 10.10.0.1 255.255.255.0
     ip nat inside
     ip virtual-reassembly
     duplex auto
     speed auto
     media-type rj45
     negotiation auto
     no keepalive
    !
    !
    !
    no ip http server
    no ip http secure-server
    ip nat inside source list 101 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 overload
    !
    access-list 101 permit ip 10.10.0.0 0.0.3.255 any
    !
    !
    control-plane
    !
    !
    line con 0
     stopbits 1
     line aux 0
     stopbits 1
     line vty 0 4
     password PASSWORD
     login
    !
    scheduler allocate 20000 1000
    !
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ip address 10.10.0.1 255.255.255.0
```

Your router will not be able to reply to the data it's being sent, because it itself is restricted to the original /24.

Change this to

```
ip address 10.10.0.1 255.255.252.0
```

Comment: Hi Mark,    thanks for your answer, I do not believe that I missed that! How stupid of me.   One quick question, do I really need the IP route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1   ?

Comment: If 192.168.1.1 is a router that gets you out to the internet, then yes. I've only seen routing to an interface like you have there when it's a PPP connection, but my experience with different types of interfaces on iOS is limited.

Comment: It is indeed a DSL router with 192.168.1.1 as the gateway address, I get allocated the 1.2 address on my 0/0. (not 1.1 as I stated in my initial question).  I assumed the ADSL router  (1.1) would indeed be the next hop. Thanks again for your time and quick, straightforward answers!